Accessing Ordered Items in DetailView for Navigation in SwiftUI
I'm new to SwiftUI and working on an app that fetches data from Firestore and displays it in a list view. When a user taps on an item, they are navigated to a detail view where they can view more information about the selected item and mark it as good by adding a bool for "g". I'm trying to implement functionality to allow the user to navigate to the previous or next item in the detail view using buttons.
The main issue I'm facing is that I cannot access the correct order of the items in the detail view. In the list view, the items are ordered correctly based on a timestamp field, but I'm unable to access this order in the detail view to properly navigate between items.
Here's a simplified version of my FirestoreDataView struct:
struct FirestoreDataView: View {
    @State private var items = [RSSItem]()
    // ... other state variables and properties
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                    NavigationLink(value: item) {
                        RSSItemRow(item: item)
                        // ... other modifiers
                    }
                }
                // ... other view modifiers
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: RSSItem.self) { item in
                if let index = items.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id }) {
                    DetailView(item: $items[index], items: items, updateGField: updateGField)
                }
            }
        }
        // ... other view modifiers
    }
    
    // ... other functions and view builders
}

In the navigationDestination modifier, I'm passing the selected item and the entire items array to the DetailView. However, when I try to navigate between items in the detail view using the navigateToItem function, I encounter issues.
Here's the relevant part of my DetailView struct:
swift
struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var item: RSSItem
    let items: [RSSItem]
    let updateGField: (RSSItem, Bool) -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        // ... detail view layout
        
        VStack {
            // ... other buttons
            
            Button(action: { navigateToItem(direction: .previous) }) {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.up.circle.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .buttonStyle(CircleButtonStyle())
            }
            Button(action: { navigateToItem(direction: .next) }) {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.down.circle.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .buttonStyle(CircleButtonStyle())
            }
        }
    }
    
    func navigateToItem(direction: NavigationDirection) {
        guard let currentIndex = items.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id }) else { return }
        
        let newIndex: Int
        switch direction {
        case .previous:
            newIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + items.count) % items.count
        case .next:
            newIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % items.count
        }
        
        item = items[newIndex]
    }
}

I've tried several approaches to solve this issue, including:

Using @Binding to pass the selected item and updating it in the navigateToItem function. However, this leads to the error:

ForEach\<Array\<RSSItem\>, String, NavigationLink\<ModifiedContent\<ModifiedContent\<ModifiedContent\<ModifiedContent\<ModifiedContent\<ModifiedContent\<ModifiedContent\<RSSItemRow, \_TraitWritingModifier\<ListRowBackgroundTraitKey\>\>, SwipeActionsModifier\<ModifiedContent\<ModifiedContent\<Button\<ModifiedContent\<Label\<Text, Image\>, \_EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier\<Optional\<Color\>\>\>\>, \_EnvironmentKeyTransformModifier\<SymbolVariants\>\>, StyleContextWriter\<SwipeActionsStyleContext\>\>\>\>, \_TraitWritingModifier\<SwipeActionsArePresent\>\>, StaticIf\<InvertedViewInputPredicate\<IsSharingPickerHost\>, SharingPickerHostModifier, EmptyModifier\>\>, SwipeActionsModifier\<ModifiedContent\<ModifiedContent\<Button\<ModifiedContent\<Label\<Text, Image\>, \_EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier\<Optional\<Color\>\>\>\>, \_EnvironmentKeyTransformModifier\<SymbolVariants\>\>, StyleContextWriter\<SwipeActionsStyleContext\>\>\>\>, \_TraitWritingModifier\<SwipeActionsArePresent\>\>, StaticIf\<InvertedViewInputPredicate\<IsSharingPickerHost\>, SharingPickerHostModifier, EmptyModifier\>\>, Never\>\>: the ID ptT73BCKD2CRgstFqB7M occurs multiple times within the collection, this will give undefined results!


Using @EnvironmentObject to share the items array across views. I created a DataModel class to hold the items array and injected it into the environment:

class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [RSSItem]()
}

struct FirestoreDataView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataModel: DataModel
    // ...
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataModel: DataModel
    // ...
}

However, this approach didn't solve the issue, and I still couldn't access the correct order of items in the detail view.
I've been struggling with this issue for a while now and would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to properly navigate between items in the detail view while maintaining the correct order from the list view.
Thank you in advance for your help!

create a viewModel with a @Published array of the items, share this viewmodel on both views.
use the following to fech the next and previous
func index(of item: someItem) -> Int? {
        return items.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id })
    }
    
    func nextItem(after item: someItem) -> SomeItemModel? {
        guard let currentIndex = index(of: item) else { return nil }
        let nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % items.count
        return items[nextIndex]
    }
    
    func previousItem(before item: someItem) -> SomeItemModel? {
        guard let currentIndex = index(of: item) else { return nil }
        let previousIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + items.count) % items.count
        return items[previousIndex]
    }

